# Should I tell my ex that he has a 3 year old son

Tags: toddler, development

I found out I was pregnant when I was 20 and naive. I had been with two men a month apart. When I found out, I thought it was my current boyfriend who was the father.  I was blinded by emotions and ignorance to understand how pregnancy works at the time. I chose him. I rejected the “real” father multiple times telling him that he was not the father ( which is what I thought). Fast forward to now.. never did a paternity test. Until now. We did an ancestry test for fun. I found out the real father is the other man. I told my boyfriend and it broke him. Do I tell the ex? I want to... because he was so passionate about being a father and I feel I robbed him. He is still in the same town as us and works near my boyfriend. I feel the close proximity requires honesty from everyone. I feel it’s best for my son. Honesty. Help me! Won’t lying hurt my sons phsyche and development more than having “two dads”?

Answer (score 2):

If it were me i would want to know that i had a child...also your child has the right to know who his real father is. It is better to have 2 loving fathers in his life then finding out years form now that you knowingly lied to him and kept his father away from him...

If you tell it now it will probably end up fine, wait to long and he might never trust you again after he finds out eventually.